# Determine if there's the condition to open keyboard by clicking UITextField

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface, uitextfield

i've a chat app where in the chat session view i have to determine if i'm the only one in the chat room to disable the click on the insertion's textfield and disable the opening of the keyboard. There is some pattern or best practies to follow?

If i open a chat where i am alone, i can simply do it in viewDidLoad method, with a simple setEnable YES/NO, but if I'm on a chatroom with a friend and he leaves, how to disable the click on the textfield dinamically?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably **implement protocol** to handle this scenario. Once your friend goes offline call a delegate function and in the event handler you can do whatever you feel best fit.

Here is a [sample tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html) to start with, you can get other references by simply googling it.

And YES it is a dynamic approach.

Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this to disable it

```
 textField.enabled = NO;
```

qnd

```
textField.enabled = YES;
```

to enable it

Comment: yeah this is pretty obvious. In view did load if i enter in an empty chat. But if i'm on a chat room and the other persone leave? i want to dinammicaly disable the click on textfield.

Comment: then use textfield.userInteractionEnabled = NO to disable that